# Using AfxEnableMemoryTracking to detect Memory leaks

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, mfc

Has anybody personally used

`AfxEnableMemoryTracking`  function provided by MFC

to detect memory leaks. How useful is it?

Comment: I've discovered this yesterday, I use it to disable the tracking in certain circumstances when the leak reports (that are being fixed by someone else) take too long to list when quitting our application in the debugger.
M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory tracking is enabled by default in MFC Debug builds. AfxEnableMemoryTracking is mostly used to temporary disable memory tracking in some code fragments, if it is necessary. To use MFC built-in memory leaks detection, ensure that every .cpp file contains the following code after all #include lines:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW 
#endif
```

Comment: Why not just define in a header?

Comment: Redefinition of new operator in h-file may cause compilation of many h-files to fail, or undefined behavior of some libraries. This is the reason why new operator is defined locally only for .cpp file.